# How to decode token after login using passport-jwt

Tags: node.js, token, passport.js

I am encoding token with the loggedin user's id with passport-jwt as below:

```
var JwtStrategy   =require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
var User          =require('../app/models/usermodel');
var config        =require('../config/database');

module.exports=function(passport){
    var opts = {}; 
    opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader();
  opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;
  passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {
    User.findOne({id: jwt_payload.id}, function(err, user) {
          if (err) {
              return done(err, false);
          }
          if (user) {
              done(null, user);
          } else {
              done(null, false);
          }
      });
  }));
};
```

and login route API:

```
apiRoutes.put('/login', function(req, res, next){
  User.findOne({email:req.body.email}, function(err, user){
    bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password, function(err, result){
       if(result){
        var token=jwt.encode(user, config.secret);
        return res.json({token:token}); 
      }else{
        return res.json("Incorrect Email and Password")
      }
    })
  })
});
```

Now I want to get loggedin user's information in dashboard page. For which I am trying to decoding token and trying to get all info of user by adding a authentication in dashboard API route as below:

```
apiRoutes.get('/dashboard', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false}), function(req, res) {
  console.log('User info: ' + req.user._id + '.');
  });
```

This above code I found in a tutorial to decode token.
So, when I hit this `/api/dashboard` url its showing an error in browser console.

```
GET http://localhost:3000/api/dashboard 401 (Unauthorized)
```

I don't know how to decode token and fetch user info. Please help me to solve this issue.

Help appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

pass token to jwt-decode like this

install `jwt-decode`:

```
npm i jwt-decode
```

and you can use it very easy:

```
import * as jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';

const payload = jwtDecode(token);
```

---

for example i used this in `nestjs` middleware:

```
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { UserType } from 'src/users/enums/user.enum';
import * as jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';

@Injectable()
export class ErrorIfNotUser implements NestMiddleware {
  use(req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) {
    const token = req.headers.authorization.slice(7);
    const payload = jwtDecode(token);

    if (payload.type !== UserType.USER) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException(
        'sorry! just type user access to this route',
      );
    }

    next();
  }
}
```

---

jwt-decode in npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure if I'm right, but I think you have mis-concept the middle-ware in express. I find an example for you.

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(cookieParser());
```

this code will use the returned value of cookieParser() to parse cookie. And here is the source code of cookieParser.

```
exports = module.exports = function cookieParser(secret, options){
  return function cookieParser(req, res, next) {
    if (req.cookies) return next();
    var cookies = req.headers.cookie;
    // main logic omits
    next();
  };
};
```

So you may see the result of cookieParser() - which is a middleware - is a function with `req, res, next` to be parameters. And also it calls `next()` to let the next middle-ware or in your case, `function(req, res) { console.log('User info: ' + req.user._id + '.'); }` to run.

So in your `passport-jwt` it supposed to return a function with parameters `req, res, next`, and calls `next()`

Comment: You meant I have to use `cookie Parser` module to decode token?

Comment: No, I mean your passport.authenticate() should follow the same style as cookie parser: return a function